# How to sort multiple mat-table in one component?

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material, mat-table

I need to sort 2 tables in one components. So far, no results, as well as console errors.

TS:

```
  displayedColumnsAgregados = ['referencia', 'descripcion', 'action']
  dataSourceAgregados = new MatTableDataSource

  displayedColumnsDisponibles = ['referencia', 'inv', 'action']
  dataSourceDisponibles = new MatTableDataSource

  @ViewChild('sortAgregados', {static: false}) sortAgregados: MatSort;
  @ViewChild('sortDisponibles', {static: false}) sortDisponibles: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm()
    this.initData()
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dataSourceDisponibles.sort = this.sortDisponibles
      this.dataSourceAgregados.sort = this.sortAgregados
    }, 200)
  }

  initData() {
    this.daoUser.getSellers().subscribe( (res:any) => this.userList = res.data)
    this.daoUser.getMechanics().subscribe( (res:any) => this.mechList = res.data)
    this.dao.getAll(this.ITEM_URL).subscribe( res => {
      this.dataSourceDisponibles = res
      this.isLoaded = true
    })
  }
```

HTML:

```
        <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceAgregados"  #sortAgregados="matSort" matSort matSortDirection="desc" style="background-color: transparent; max-height: 370px;">

          <ng-container matColumnDef="referencia">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef fxFlex="15%" style="justify-content: flex-start" mat-sort-header>Ref.</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let el" fxFlex="15%" style="justify-content: flex-start">
              {{el.referencia}}
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
..



        <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceDisponibles" #sortDisponibles="matSort" matSort matSortDirection="desc" style="background-color: transparent; max-height: 370px;">


          <ng-container matColumnDef="referencia">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="justify-content: flex-start" mat-sort-header>Ref.</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let el" style="justify-content: flex-start">{{el.referencia}}</mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
..
```

Can someone help me to solve these unexpected, fabulous, interesting, sharpie, alluring and complicated problems, please?

Comment: Can you share more details on the console errors that you are getting? Also, what is up with the text at the end? It doesn't seem to be relevant to the problem.

Comment: No console errors.

Comment: Can you pls put your code into stackblitz?

Comment: https://angular-nvdj5p.stackblitz.io. Now sorting works .. But on my local machine not .....